# Multiline Formatting of else Statements in C/C++ without Braces

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am rewriting some C++ code, I have the following

```
if (ConfidenceBias.value > 0) *normalInfo = tree.setDataField(NormalSigs(), *samples, *sampleData, density, pointWeightSum, ConversionAndBiasFunction);
else *normalInfo = tree.setDataField(NormalSigs(), *samples, *sampleData, density, pointWeightSum, ConversionFunction); ThreadPool::Parallel_for(0, normalInfo->size(), [&](unsigned int, size_t i) { (*normalInfo)[i] *= (Real)-1.; });
```

I assume that this is equivalent to

```
if (ConfidenceBias.value > 0) 
{
    *normalInfo = tree.setDataField(NormalSigs(), *samples, *sampleData, density, pointWeightSum, ConversionAndBiasFunction);
}
else 
{
    *normalInfo = tree.setDataField(NormalSigs(), *samples, *sampleData, density, pointWeightSum, ConversionFunction);  
}

ThreadPool::Parallel_for(0, normalInfo->size(), [&](unsigned int, size_t i) { (*normalInfo)[i] *= (Real)-1.; });
```

but there is a slight conern that the compiler is interpreting the original as

```
if (ConfidenceBias.value > 0) 
{
    *normalInfo = tree.setDataField(NormalSigs(), *samples, *sampleData, density, pointWeightSum, ConversionAndBiasFunction);
}
else 
{
    *normalInfo = tree.setDataField(NormalSigs(), *samples, *sampleData, density, pointWeightSum, ConversionFunction);  
    ThreadPool::Parallel_for(0, normalInfo->size(), [&](unsigned int, size_t i) { (*normalInfo)[i] *= (Real)-1.; });
}
```

I cannot find a reference to what the VSVC compiler does anywhere. Which is it?

Comment: "*there is a slight conern that the compiler is interpreting the original as*" any reasoning why it should do so?

Comment: "*rewriting some C code*" this code definitely is no C code.

Comment: No, not really, I just can't find a reference to how the compiler deals with multiple statement after an else without braces and I find it odd why someone would write it this way without it meaning something...

Comment: "C-style" code then.

Comment: @alk can you advise? I assume it is the former case?

Comment: @MoonKnight Your first interpretation is correct, but the code is certainly badly formatted. It almost seems that the author might have intended the code to be equivalent to your second interpretation. It is (depending on style guidelines used) pretty normal to skip braces on single statements in control-flow blocks in both C and C++. There is nothing C-style about it. But at least the statements should be properly indented to show where in the control flow they belong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK your assumption about the code is correct.

For most languages I am ware of only one statement or a compound-statement (e.g. braces) will be executed on the condition.

The

```
ThreadPool::Parallel_for(0, normalInfo->size(), [&](unsigned int, size_t i) { (*normalInfo)[i] *= (Real)-1.; });
```

line is really really oddly hidden after the condition and I would assume this a code smell because it makes code hard to read, understand and debug.

---

Edit because I like complete answers: Also you actually do not need to know what VS C++ compiler is going to do here because this is defined. See [Alex Allain's post](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson2.html) about this.

Refer to the MSDN docs for this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/cpp/statements-cpp?view=vs-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/cpp/if-else-statement-cpp?view=vs-2019
states

> Controls conditional branching. Statements in the if-block are
>   executed only if the if-expression evaluates to a non-zero value (or
>   TRUE). If the value of expression is nonzero, statement1 and any other
>   statements in the block are executed and the else-block, if present,
>   is skipped. If the value of expression is zero, then the if-block is
>   skipped and the else-block, if present, is executed. Expressions that
>   ...

To understand this check the definition of [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/cpp/expression-statement?view=vs-2019):

> Expression statements cause expressions to be evaluated. No transfer
>   of control or iteration takes place as a result of an expression
>   statement.
>
> The syntax for the expression statement is simply Syntax
>
> ```
> [expression ] ;
> ```

and here is the [compound statement block definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/cpp/compound-statements-blocks?view=vs-2019)

> A compound statement consists of zero or more statements enclosed in
>   curly braces ({ }). A compound statement can be used anywhere a
>   statement is expected. Compound statements are commonly called
>   "blocks." Syntax
>
> ```
> { [ statement-list ] }
> ```

Verdict: Your assumption was valid, your fear unfounded :)

Comment: Incredible answer, thanks very much for your time here, it is most appreciated.

Comment: Expression statements are only one kind of possible statement that can appear as single statement instead of a compound-statement with braces.

Comment: You can find the authoritative grammar in the C++ standard. See [\[stmt.select\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.select#1): After `else` follows one *statement*, which in [\[stmt.stmt\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#nt:statement) is defined as either one of a list of single statements or a *compound-statement*, which according to [\[stmt.block\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.block#nt:compound-statement) is a sequence of statements enclosed by braces.